# UV mapping texture problem

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm doing this course about modeling and UV mapping in blender, the course goes through modeling of an apartment and I'm trying to texture the couch, for some reason the texture in the pillows is broken:
[image: Couch]

This is the link to the file: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/17X0Mek2GHQeFSZGikP83-QJYM_rz9Vjj
Would appreciate any help :)

Comment: You haven't UV unwrapped the objects yet, every mesh seems to have the default cube UV map. You need to *Mark Seams* to the geometry of each object and properly UV unwrap them to get rid of those stretches in textures. Don't know if this is covered in the course you're taking, but you can check blender guru's tutorials about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeBUfMKKZDo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scPSP_U858k

Comment: The texture is "broken" because the UV isn't good.  It looks like you've applied some subdivision; your course may be out of date with respect to the way that Blender does UV smoothing with a subdivision modifier.  If your course is out of date, you should consider watching one or more tutorials on UV unwrapping or UV editing in Blender, followed by some experimentation.  Many free tutorials are available, and perfectly sufficient for getting started on understanding UV mapping.